# Make an ajax request without extending identity auth expiration

Tags: asp.net-core, session, identity

I have:

> ```
>    //[SessionState(SessionStateBehavior.Disabled)]
>    public async Task<IActionResult> CheckServerTimeoutDateTime()
>    {
>        var minutesRemaining = (DateTime.Parse(((await AuthenticationHttpContextExtensions
>                                         .AuthenticateAsync(HttpContext))
>                                         .Properties
>                                         .Items)[".expires"])
>                 .Subtract(DateTime.Now)
>                 .TotalSeconds) / 60;
>
>        return Json( new { message = minutesRemaining });
>    }
> ```

This lets me grab the current remaining time in the session.  However, the funny catch-22 is that running this ajax call itself extends the session time.  Is there a good approach in Core (.NET 5) to disabling the sliding of the Identity auth expiration for just a single request?

Note: I have commented out the annotation on the first line: [SessionState(SessionStateBehavior.Disabled)] because it seems not to work in Core any longer.

Comment: You could consider storing the expiration time in cookie, then when you want to check the remaining time, you can get the expiration time from cookie and compare with current time, without to send a request to the server side.

Comment: I understand. But that would only be accurate as of the last request / page load. The purpose is to compare the server timeout live value with the client timeout live value so I need to be able to get the exact, current value at any time.